# Do Polycarbonates (lexan) block wifi

Tags: wifi

I am trying to figure out if WiFi from TP-Link N450 Wireless WiFi Router could reliably get through lexan. I need the wifi to be able to have a constant, reliable signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LEXAN  has low absorption and reflection to WiFi as long as not touching say a dielectric antenna where it might shift tuning but unlikely in your situation.